# enable oci8 extension in php 7.0.9

Tags: php, oracle, xampp, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I have XAMPP for Windows 7.0.9 installed and need to use the oci8 extension
I downloaded the instantclient `instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0`
and the ODBC `instantclient-odbc-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0` and unzip them into `C:\instantclient_12_1` i added this path into system variable.
I downloaded `oci8-2.0.12` and unzip it into `C:\xampp\php\ext`.
in the php.ini there were only on line in the extensions about oci8 and it was uncommented already
`extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client`
I restarted the laptop for the system variable to change.
when i open the xampp nothing changed and the oci8 didn't appear in the phpinfo.
What i need to do to enable oci??